# pg_connect error when using php-cli

Tags: php, postgresql, centos, command-line-interface

I recently updated PHP from 5.2.10 to 5.3.3 and now I have problems when executing PHP scripts from command line, i receive an error "Call to undefined function pg_connect()" so it seems that cli does not recognize the php53-pgsql module

From the browser works fine but I need to execute scripts from command line

I have a Centos 5.5 and postgres 8.4

Comment: SOLVED: I checked the phpinfo of the php-cli and said it was php version 5.2.16 !! it seems that in the installation the 5.3 was installed ok on /usr/bin/php  but /usr/local/bin/php had version 5.2 so I replaced it and now works fine!

Comment: Post this as answer and accept it, so your question does not linger as unanswered, please.

Answer (score 2):

I checked the phpinfo of the php-cli and said it was php version 5.2.16 !! It seems that in the installation the 5.3 was installed ok on `/usr/bin/php` but `/usr/local/bin/php` had version 5.2 so I replaced it and now works fine!